# When is ShutterCallback fired?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I would like to make an app to trigger external flash when your phone is taking a picture.

I have no experience with Camera API, and I didn't quite understand what this description of the Camera.ShutterCallback means:

> "Called as near as possible to the moment when a photo is captured
>   from the sensor."

Does that mean that it is fired just *before* the sensor starts capturing the image, or just *after* the sensor started capturing the image?

Comment: Its first in the line of callbacks (1-ShutterCallback, 2-PictureCallback) and is called immediately when photo is captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, "This may be some time after the photo was triggered" implies that it will be after. It's meant to be a hook to provide feedback that the camera is working, like a sound or animation.

Comment: Ah, thanks, somehow I overlooked that part of the text.